# Allow blank on should validate_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shoulda

Using shoulda, any ideas how to allow blank when having this test:

```
should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured it out!! The validate_uniqueness_of relies on the value for the attribute you are currently testing on the first record in the database. So, if the first record in the database happens to be blank or nul for that attribute your test will always give an error like this: "Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:customer_number).case_insensitive.scoped_to(:user_id) } Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when customer_number is set to nil, got no errors".

So how do we fix this? Make sure you delete all existing records and that the first record contains a filled in value for the attribute.

model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :customer_number, :scope => :user_id, :case_sensitive => false, :allow_blank => true, :allow_nil => true
```

model spec:

```
describe 'Validation' do

  it { should allow_value('').for(:customer_number) }

  describe 'When a user exists with the same customer_number and user' do
    before(:each) do 
      Customer.destroy_all
      # Saving a single customer to validate uniqueness.
      @existing = Factory(:customer, :customer_number => 'test') # If you leave customer_number blank here the matcher will check if it can save a new record with a blank customer_number which is possible since we allow blanks. So make sure your first record has a filled in value!!
    end

    subject do
      Factory.build(:customer)
    end

    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:customer_number).case_insensitive.scoped_to(:user_id) }
  end
end
```

Hope this cleared up some people's issues :)

Comment: This is the best explanation for this test failure (which seems quite a common issue!). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
should allow_value(" ").for(:email)
should allow_value(nil).for(:email)
```

Comment: I still get "Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when email is set to nil, got no errors" when running should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).

Answer (score -3):

maybe

```
should validate_uniqueness_of(:email, :allow_blank => true)
```